Is it normal gas + transaction payment with failed transaction?
Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
Value:
0 ETH
($0.00)
Transaction Fee:0.018749190625 ETH ($49.47)
Gas Price: 3.125 Gwei (0.000000003125 ETH)
Gas Limit & Usage by Txn: 6,000,000 | 5,999,741 (100%)
Gas Fees: Base: 1.001109365 Gwei
Burnt Fees: Burnt: 0.006006396902674465 ETH ($15.85)
60 USD - without any result. The Ethers just flew out of the wallet.

0x04b0cdc2443cf68cb3e3accdab7189c47203276d9afba17510961f284515bee5 - transaction cache

Failed with out of gas.
It likely showed you it would fail or would have with an eth_Call, and so could not calculate the correct amount of gas to complete.
But it has been sent anyway and so the gas used to compute operations up till that point has been burned.
Contract fails at:
_balances[to] += value; at in 0x025b555d25f387d9e1a7ebea7c0c9655431e2f42
EuropeanMedicalExchange


While calling transfer/update which it seems to do until all gas is burned.

Could try with a shorter list of beneficiary.
